# How do replace ExUnit.Case.__on_definition__?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to help out in updating some code for an Elixir project but got stuck on this, this part of the code :

```
ExUnit.Case.__on_definition__(__ENV__, message, [])

       def unquote(message)(unquote(var))  do
         unquote(contents)
       end

       def unquote(:"__#{message}__")(), do: [file: __ENV__.file, line: __ENV__.line]
      end
```

How do I replace the `ExUnit.Case.__on_definition__(__ENV__, message, [])` ?

Comment: Does changing the `__on_definition__` line to `ExUnit.Case.register_test(__ENV__, message, [])` work?

Comment: Used this `ExUnit.Case.register_test(__ENV__, message, [], [])`

Comment: Please see my answer. I think that's what you need to do to get equivalent behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExUnit.Case.__on_definition__/3` [was renamed to](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/9441db270306751ed3dbc3b3a34684ae97d7651e)  `ExUnit.Case.register_test/3` and later [gained a `type` argument](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/056536add75accc02542ef84d48c8535127c4171) to become `ExUnit.Case.register_test/4`. Both these changes occurred before 1.3.0. So, to get the equivalent of:

```
ExUnit.Case.__on_definition__(__ENV__, message, [])
```

in 1.3.0, you need to do:

```
ExUnit.Case.register_test(__ENV__, :test, message, [])
```

[Source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/056536add75accc02542ef84d48c8535127c4171#diff-da9b91caf1cd02e59ee50c01929a2058R259)